How to play multiple instruments on a MidiSequence in Swift?
I am trying to create a midi app in SwiftUI. I would like to play two instruments in a song.
I have created a test app based on code I found on the internet.
First you should hear some notes of violin, then piano. However, after playing the first note, all the following notes are played with piano sound.
How can I solve this?
The code is as follows:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var player = MidiPlayer()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            
            Button(action: playSong) {
                
                Text("Hello, world!")
                
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            
            playSong()
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func playSong() {
        
        let composer = SongComposer()
        let song = composer.compose()

        player.prepareSong(song: song)

        player.playSong()

    }
    
}

import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class MidiPlayer: ObservableObject {

    var midiPlayer: AVMIDIPlayer?
    var bankURL: URL
    
    init() {
    
        guard let bankURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Nokia_Tongbao_Bank__Series_30__8-bit", withExtension: "sf2") else {
        
            fatalError("\"Nokia_Tongbao_Bank__Series_30__8-bit.sf2\" file not found.")
            
        }
        
        self.bankURL = bankURL
        
    }
    
    func prepareSong(song: Song) {
    
        var data: Unmanaged<CFData>?
        
        guard MusicSequenceFileCreateData(song.musicSequence!, MusicSequenceFileTypeID.midiType, MusicSequenceFileFlags.eraseFile, 480, &data) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
        
            fatalError("Cannot create music midi data")
            
        }
        
        if let md = data {
        
            let midiData = md.takeUnretainedValue() as Data
            
            do {
            
                try self.midiPlayer = AVMIDIPlayer(data: midiData, soundBankURL: self.bankURL)
                
            } catch let error {
            
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                
            }

        }
        
        self.midiPlayer!.prepareToPlay()

    }
    
    func playSong() {
    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
        if let md = self.midiPlayer {
        
            md.currentPosition = 0
        md.play()
            
        }

        }

    }

}

import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Song {

    var musicSequence: MusicSequence?
    var tracks: [Int: MusicTrack] = [:]
    
    init() {
    
        guard NewMusicSequence(&musicSequence) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
        
            fatalError("Cannot create MusicSequence")
            
        }
        
    }

func addTrack(instrumentId: UInt8) -> Int {

    var track: MusicTrack?
    
    guard MusicSequenceNewTrack(musicSequence!, &track) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
    
        fatalError("Cannot add track")
        
    }
    
    let trackId = tracks.count
    tracks[trackId] = track
    
    var inMessage = MIDIChannelMessage(status: 0xC0, data1: instrumentId, data2: 0, reserved: 0)
    MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent(track!, 0, &inMessage)

    return trackId
    
}

func setTempo(tempo: Float64) {

    let timeStamp = MusicTimeStamp(0)
    
    var tempoTrack: MusicTrack?
    MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(musicSequence! ,&tempoTrack)
    
    removeTempoEvents(tempoTrack: tempoTrack!)
    
    MusicTrackNewExtendedTempoEvent(tempoTrack!, timeStamp, tempo)

}

private func removeTempoEvents(tempoTrack: MusicTrack) {

    var tempIter: MusicEventIterator?
    NewMusicEventIterator(tempoTrack, &tempIter)
    
    var hasEvent: DarwinBoolean = false
    MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(tempIter!, &hasEvent)
    
    while (hasEvent == true) {
    
        var stamp = MusicTimeStamp(0)
        var type: MusicEventType = 0
        var data: UnsafeRawPointer? = nil
        var sizeData: UInt32 = 0
        
        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(tempIter!, &stamp, &type, &data, &sizeData)
        
        if (type == kMusicEventType_ExtendedTempo) {
        
            MusicEventIteratorDeleteEvent(tempIter!);
            MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(tempIter!, &hasEvent)
            
        } else {
        
            MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(tempIter!)
            MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(tempIter!, &hasEvent)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    DisposeMusicEventIterator(tempIter!)

}

    func addNote(trackId: Int, note: UInt8, duration: Float, position: Float) {
    
      let time = MusicTimeStamp(position)
      
      var musicNote = MIDINoteMessage(channel: 0,
                                      note: note,
                                      velocity: 64,
                                      releaseVelocity: 0,
                                      duration: duration)
                                      

        guard MusicTrackNewMIDINoteEvent(tracks[trackId]!, time, &musicNote) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
      
            fatalError("Cannot add Note")
          
        }
      
    }
}

import Foundation

class SongComposer {

    func compose() -> Song {
    
        let song = Song()
        song.setTempo(tempo: 240)
        var currentPosition: Float = 0
        
        
        let trackId = song.addTrack(instrumentId: 48)

        for _ in 0...1 {
        
            song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 64,
                      duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                      
            currentPosition += 1.0
            
            song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 63,
                      duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                      
            currentPosition += 1.0
            
        }
        
        song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 64,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                  
        currentPosition += 1.0
        
        song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 59,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                  
        currentPosition += 1.0
        
        song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 62,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
        
currentPosition += 2.0

song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 57, duration: 3.0, position:currentPosition)
song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 45, duration: 3.0, position:currentPosition)

        currentPosition -= 1.0
        
        song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 60,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                  
        currentPosition += 4.0
        
        // track 2
        
        let track2Id = song.addTrack(instrumentId: 00)

        for _ in 0...1 {
        
            song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 64,
                      duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                      
            currentPosition += 1.0
            
            song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 63,
                      duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                      
            currentPosition += 1.0
            
        }
        
        song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 64,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                  
        currentPosition += 1.0
        
        song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 59,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                  
        currentPosition += 1.0
        
        song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 62,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
        
currentPosition += 2.0

song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 57, duration: 3.0, position:currentPosition)
song.addNote(trackId: trackId, note: 45, duration: 3.0, position:currentPosition)

        currentPosition -= 1.0
        
        song.addNote(trackId: track2Id, note: 60,
                  duration: 1.0, position: currentPosition)
                  
        return song
        
    }

}

Thanks in advance.

I think you're not going to accomplish this with a simple AVMidiPlayer.

I suspect it must be possible. What else is the point of being able to add different tracks? The question is ofcourse how ;-)
Or is there another way than with AVMidiPlayer to achieve this?

You may have a look at: Play multi-instrument MIDI file IOS, and see if you can adapt that to swift.

I finaly found the solution for my problem. I made the following changes to the code:

Set a timestamp for the MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent function.
Added an extra function, namely setInstrument()
Added the function getStatus() so the MIDIChannelMessage is send to the richt channel
In the initializer MIDINoteMessage the channel is set to the trackId, so that each track uses its own channel.

Below the modified code for the Song class:
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Song {

    var musicSequence: MusicSequence?
    var tracks: [Int: MusicTrack] = [:]
    
    init() {
    
        guard NewMusicSequence(&musicSequence) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
        
            fatalError("Cannot create MusicSequence")
            
        }
        
    }

func addTrack(instrumentId: UInt8) -> Int {

    var track: MusicTrack?
    
    guard MusicSequenceNewTrack(musicSequence!, &track) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
    
        fatalError("Cannot add track")
        
    }
    
    let trackId = tracks.count
    tracks[trackId] = track
    
    let time = MusicTimeStamp(0.0)
      
    var inMessage = MIDIChannelMessage(status: self.getStatus(trackId: trackId), data1: instrumentId, data2: 0, reserved: 0)
    MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent(track!, time, &inMessage)

    return trackId
    
}

    func setInstrument(trackId: Int, instrumentId: UInt8, position: Float) {

        if let track = self.tracks[trackId] {
            
              let time = MusicTimeStamp(position)

            var inMessage = MIDIChannelMessage(status: self.getStatus(trackId: trackId), data1: instrumentId, data2: 0, reserved: 0)
        MusicTrackNewMIDIChannelEvent(track, time, &inMessage)

        }
            
    }
    
    private func getStatus(trackId: Int) -> UInt8 {
        
        switch trackId {
            
        case 0:
            return 0xC0
        case 1:
            return 0xC1
        case 2:
            return 0xC2
        case 3:
            return 0xC3
        case 4:
            return 0xC4
        case 5:
            return 0xC5
        case 6:
            return 0xC6
        case 7:
            return 0xC7
        case 8:
            return 0xC8
        case 9:
            return 0xC9
        case 10:
            return 0xCA
        case 11:
            return 0xCB
        case 12:
            return 0xCC
        case 13:
            return 0xCD
        case 14:
            return 0xCE
        case 15:
            return 0xCF
        default:
            return 0xC0
            
        }
        
    }
    
func setTempo(tempo: Float64) {

    let timeStamp = MusicTimeStamp(0)
    
    var tempoTrack: MusicTrack?
    MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(musicSequence! ,&tempoTrack)
    
    removeTempoEvents(tempoTrack: tempoTrack!)
    
    MusicTrackNewExtendedTempoEvent(tempoTrack!, timeStamp, tempo)

}

private func removeTempoEvents(tempoTrack: MusicTrack) {

    var tempIter: MusicEventIterator?
    NewMusicEventIterator(tempoTrack, &tempIter)
    
    var hasEvent: DarwinBoolean = false
    MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(tempIter!, &hasEvent)
    
    while (hasEvent == true) {
    
        var stamp = MusicTimeStamp(0)
        var type: MusicEventType = 0
        var data: UnsafeRawPointer? = nil
        var sizeData: UInt32 = 0
        
        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(tempIter!, &stamp, &type, &data, &sizeData)
        
        if (type == kMusicEventType_ExtendedTempo) {
        
            MusicEventIteratorDeleteEvent(tempIter!);
            MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(tempIter!, &hasEvent)
            
        } else {
        
            MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(tempIter!)
            MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(tempIter!, &hasEvent)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    DisposeMusicEventIterator(tempIter!)

}

    func addNote(trackId: Int, note: UInt8, duration: Float, position: Float) {
    
      let time = MusicTimeStamp(position)
      
        var musicNote = MIDINoteMessage(channel: UInt8(trackId <= 15 ? trackId : 0),
                                      note: note,
                                      velocity: 64,
                                      releaseVelocity: 0,
                                      duration: duration)
                                      

        guard MusicTrackNewMIDINoteEvent(tracks[trackId]!, time, &musicNote) == OSStatus(noErr) else {
      
            fatalError("Cannot add Note")
          
        }
      
    }
    
}

Happy programming!
Kristof Nijs
